# Apple Allow Audio output Device programmatically handling?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, core-audio

I am trying to understand. Apple allow the Change Audio output device programmatically? Or Applye only allow input devices.

my applciation have the Video calling feature and now i want to seprate input device and output devices.

I am not sure Apple allow output deives to handled programmatically or not fro iPhone/iPad not mac

Need clearification or Apple docuements or any other

Thanks to all.